# curl a url and get only body back not entire html file

Tags: bash, curl

I have the url `mydomain.com/get`

At that url I serve an `index.html`.

That `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        12345
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to use bash to return `12345`. I'm doing this via jenkins so I can't install specific things. I was thinking grep?

```
curl mydomain.com/get | grep ???
```

Comment: You need a HTML parser; I recommend using a language like Python which can fetch the result, parse it, and return the body in a single script.

Comment: I assume your example is incorrect. The `</html>` tag doesn’t have the corresponding `<html>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: your HTML doesn't look like valid XML. I have changed it to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        12345
    </body>
</html>
```

Using [XMLstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) (xml) you can now extract the value of the body element with

```
$ curl mydomain.com/get | xml select -t -v /html/body

        12345
```

Answer (score 0):

With a shell that supports process substitution (such as bash) and if you have `xmllint` you can write something like:

```
echo 'cat //*[local-name()="body"]/text()' | xmllint --shell <(curl mydomain.com/get) | grep -v '^/ >'
```

Please note this will only return the text value in the `<body>` tag. If you have a more complex page you’ll need a more advanced command.

Comment: I struggled to implement it in a Makefile. So here is my solution
`curl mydomain.com/get | xmllint --xpath "string(//body)" - ` which also outputs only the body content

Comment: @MiW That works too, and this is a better solution for simply getting the body string.

Answer (score -1):

Try
`sed -n '/<body>/,/<\/body>/p'`. This should find the text between the starting and end body tags.

Comment: This prints both the start and end tags, which is not what the OP wanted.